# webscraping in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the website property 24 website.
However it returns extra data rows which is not on the page. Here is my code.

```
library(rvest)
property<- read_html("https://www.property24.com/houses-for-sale/cape-
   town/western-cape/432")
price <-property%>% html_nodes(".p24_price") %>% html_text()
desc  <-property%>% html_nodes(".p24_excerpt")%>%html_text()
title <-property%>% html_nodes(".p24_title")%>%html_text() 



price = gsub("[^0-9]","", price) 
desc = gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", desc) 
desc = gsub("\r\n", "", desc) 
desc = strtrim(desc,100)

property_table<-data.frame(price,title,desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `price`, `title`, `desc` vectors have different lengths.

Why is that? Look at their contents.

You will find that some values don't look like a proper price or description.
Because the patterns `.p24_price` and `.p24_excerpt` are not specific enough.
You need to look at the page source, and make the patterns more specific.
For example this will be better:

```
price <- property %>% html_nodes(".p24_content .p24_price") %>% html_text()
desc  <- property %>% html_nodes(".p24_content .p24_excerpt") %>% html_text()
title <- property %>% html_nodes(".p24_content .p24_title") %>% html_text()
```

But I see at least one more problem.
Some properties have more than one price,
for example:

> From R 12 250 000 to R 13 995 999

So the way you extract the price part using `gsub` needs improvement too.